# How to clear or initialize imagelist for began game again?

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a game for 43 image from imagelist as random and 1 picturebox for display , and I have 43 button , I would to clear imagelist when I click the button "starr" for began the game without reset form.

My code just for first 4 button

```
Public Class Form1

    'Random Class included in .NET
    Private RND As New Random

    Dim ImageIndexes As New List(Of Integer)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
okkk:   'Populate the array with the Index of each Image in the ImageList
        For i As Integer = 0 To ImageList1.Images.Count - 1
            ImageIndexes.Add(i)
        Next i

    End Sub


    Private Sub Buttons_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click,
        Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click
        CType(sender, Button).Visible = False
        Dim ArrayIndex As Integer = RND.Next(0, ImageIndexes.Count)
        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(ImageIndexes(ArrayIndex))
        ImageIndexes.Remove(ArrayIndex)

    End Sub

    Private Sub starr_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles starr.Click

        ImageIndexes.Clear()
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        Button1.Visible = True
        Button2.Visible = True
        Button3.Visible = True
        Button3.Visible = True
        Button4.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why don't you just reload your index collection?  `        For i As Integer = 0 To ImageList1.Images.Count - 1
            ImageIndexes.Add(i)
        Next i
`

Comment: thomas aha thank u , but can u write me the code for reload index , i m beginner in visuel basic , thanks u again